# Getting error on tikzcd: No shape named tikz@f@1-2-1 is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I'm trying to use tikz-cd but I can't seem to solve this problem. When I try to compile the following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
U \times F \arrow[r, "\phi"] \arrow[d, "\pr_1"] & \pi^{-1}(U) \arrow[d, "\pi"] \\
                                                                         & U
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@1-2-1 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
...
l.12 I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1.
\errmessage ...currentrow -\tikzcd@currentcolumn }

l.14 \end{tikzcd}

?
```

I've tried googling similar errors but they seem to occur in wildly different situations. Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, `tikz-cd` finds nothing at the position `2-1` when attempts to draw the downwards arrow; if yo *really* want an arrow pointing "to nowhere" help it a little with something not visible. `{}` will do:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
U \times F \arrow[r, "\phi"] \arrow[d, "\pr_1"] & \pi^{-1}(U) \arrow[d, "\pi"] \\
                                                                          {} & U
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

But, perhaps, you meant not a `d` (downwards), but a `dr` (downwards and to the right) arrow, which makes more sense:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
U \times F \arrow[r, "\phi"] \arrow[dr, "\pr_1",swap] & \pi^{-1}(U) \arrow[d, "\pi"] \\
& U
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Or this:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
U \times F \arrow[rr, "\phi"] \arrow[dr, "\pr_1",swap] &  & \pi^{-1}(U) \arrow[dl, "\pi"] \\
& U &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way I could get the $U$ on the bottom centered between the two things on the top, instead of being directly below the $\pi^{-1}(U)$?

Comment: @Pedro Sure: use an additional column. See my updated answer.